# How do you scale a svg img to fit container?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]So I have two svg images and one is positioned left, and one is positioned right. They both have a height of 100% and a width of 50%. The images are not scaling to fit the container and I have tried everything. I've tried to fiddle with the viewbox but can't quite get it. The preserveAspectRatio almost gets it with none but it squashes the images when you resize the browser. Slice almost gets it but one picture overlaps the other. I have tried everything but is coming up empty. Does anyone have any suggestion? I'm trying to get rid of the white space and have the picture cover the background but css background: cover does not work.

Here's my code:

```
header {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    // background: black;

    .airplane {
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

    .wings {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        // background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(black, 0.))
    }

    .airplaneleft {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        // background: red;
        animation: left 2s forwards;
    }

    .airplaneright {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        // background: black;
        animation: right 2s forwards;
    }



HTML

<header>
        <div class="menu">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul class="links">
                <li class="link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="link"><a href="#">Aviation</a></li>
                <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="link"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="intro">
            <h1 class="name"><span class="first">Jovan </span class="last"><span>Elmore</span></h1>
            <h2 class="title">Aviation Specalist</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="airplane">
            <img class="airplaneleft wings" src="\imgs\FfRZvZFh01.svg" alt="left side of airplane">
            <img class="airplaneright wings" src="\imgs\VRjCKGg201.svg" alt="right side of airplane">
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Can you bring an image  what result do you need to reach? Or a live example of your current code?

Comment: @focus.style I have the image. I'm trying to get into to cover the background but css background:cover isn't working.

Comment: I see a lot of background properties and non backbround-image. Are you using only 2 this images? Ore there are some more? Can you upload all images somewhere and drop a link here, so i could test you code?

Comment: @focus.style I think I might have found a problem. When I use the svg inline the width and the height property works. When I don't they don't have any affect if they are in a different folder. Here are the pictures. https://codepen.io/jalissaw/pen/gOaEvXg

Comment: @focus.style Yeah, I'm only using two images.

Comment: Give me couple of minutes. I will post an answer

Comment: @focus.style. Thanks for all your help but that didn't work but I think I just stumbled into an answer with the help of your code. I deleted the div around the imgs and the code to that as well. It's doing what I want it to do for now.

Comment: Great to here that! +1 will nice if the my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This will center the wings vertically and set them in line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>

    <style>
    header {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

      .airplane {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
      }

      .wings {
        position: a
          width: 50%;
          height: auto;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          position: absolute;
      }

      .airplaneleft {
          left: 0;
          animation: left 2s forwards;
      }

      .airplaneright {
          right: 0;
          animation: right 2s forwards;
      }



    </style>

</head>
<body>

  <header>
          <div class="menu">
              <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
              <span></span>
          </div>
          <nav class="navbar">
              <ul class="links">
                  <li class="link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li class="link"><a href="#">Aviation</a></li>
                  <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="link"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="intro">
              <h1 class="name"><span class="first">Jovan </span class="last"><span>Elmore</span></h1>
              <h2 class="title">Aviation Specalist</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="airplane">
              <img class="airplaneleft wings" src="2.svg" alt="left side of airplane">
              <img class="airplaneright wings" src="1.svg" alt="right side of airplane">
          </div>
      </header>

</body>
</html>
```